# Password Not Mixing With Salt CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a security class which mixes up mixed numbers and codes. But when I try to hash my password with codeigniter sha1 does not pick up extra symbols only sha1.

I need to be able to get my ekey function mixing in with sha1

**Model**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->helper('date');
$this->load->library('security/ecryptkey');
$this->load->helper('string');
}

public function addUser($username, $firstname, $lastname, $password, $email) {

$salt = substr($this->ecryptkey->ekey(), 0, 32);

$data = array(
'username' => $username,
'firstname' => $firstname,
'lastname' => $lastname,
'password' => sha1($salt. sha1($password)),
'email' => $email
);

return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
}
```

**Library File**

```
class Ecryptkey {

public function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->helper('string');
}

function ekey() {
    $chars = array(
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
    'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '?', '!', '@', '#', ':', ';','~','`',
    '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '|', ';', '/', '=', '+','.','-','+'
    );
   shuffle($chars);
   $num_chars = count($chars) - 1;
   $token = '';
   for ($i = 0; $i < $num_chars; $i++){
      $token .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $num_chars)];
   }
   return $token;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SHA-1 algorithm is designed to return 160 bits of information. In the case of the PHP implementation without the optional "raw_output" parameter being set to TRUE, this equates to 40 hex characters (or 20 binary characters if it is set to true).

I believe your ekey method is working as it should, as is the SHA1 method, unless there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: I can not see the salt that is in my salt row. Which should be mixed in with sha1

Comment: Which salt row? Do you mean the salt variable within your add user function?

Comment: I thought I should be able see the $salt in the password as well as sha1

Comment: No, as I said in my answer, SHA1 is designed to return 40 characters. It will return 40 if you hash your password, 40 if you hash your salt, and 40 if you do it the way you're doing it currently. Are you seeing 40 characters in your current output?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to make my own password hasher now so do not need sha1 and can get my salt working with it

```
public function addUser($username, $firstname, $lastname, $password, $email) {
$salt = $this->ecryptkey->crypt();

$data = array(
'username' => $username,
'firstname' => $firstname,
'lastname' => $lastname,
'salt' => $salt,
'password' => $this->ecryptkey->hash_password($password).$salt,
'email' => $email
);

return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
}
```